# how save value of checkbox after close the app in android?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, save

I want save the state of checkbox after close the app
what I should to do?
I don't know how I do that with list view and arrayadapter 
how use sharedpreferences here?

in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word_list);


        MyAdView.SetAd((AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView));


        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayList<Word> worda = new ArrayList<>();

        worda.add(new Word("The B",R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
        worda.add(new Word("The B",R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));



        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, worda);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);



        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TheBossBabyS1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }        });
    }
}
```

in Word.java

```
public class Word {

    private String mConversation;

    private int mImageResourceId = NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;

    public static final int NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED = -1;



    public Word(String conversation){

        mConversation = conversation;

    }

    public Word(String conversation, int imageResourceId){

        mConversation = conversation;

        mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;

    }


    public String getConversation(){
        return  mConversation;
    }

    public int getImageResourceId(){ return mImageResourceId; }

    public boolean hasImage(){
        return mImageResourceId != NO_IMAGE_PROVIDED;
    }


}
```

in WordAdapter.java

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private int mColorResourceId;

    public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> worda){

        super(context, 0, worda);

    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


        View listItemView = convertView;

        if(listItemView == null)
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        Word currentWord = (Word) getItem(position);


        TextView convTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.conv_text_view);

        convTextView.setText(currentWord.getConversation());


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        if(currentWord.hasImage()) {
            imageView.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceId());

            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        checkbox.setFocusable(false);
        checkbox.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);


        View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container2);

        textContainer.setBackgroundColor(((position % 2) == 0) ? Color.parseColor("#B2DFDB") : Color.parseColor("#80CBC4"));

        return listItemView;

    }
}
```

in list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/tan_background"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/text_container2"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/conv_text_view"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="lutti" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
       />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you'd like to write code that is used when an app is closed, you can override onPause() and onDestroy(). onPause() is called when the home/power button is hit, but the instance is still loaded. onDestroy() is called when the app is fully closed and the instance has been destroyed. If you want to save it even after the instance is destroyed, you would have to create some kind of data storage/database

Answer (score 0):

Use  sharedpreferences to store the result.

```
boolean isChecked=false;
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
if(checkBox.isChecked()){

isChecked=true;

}
 editor.putBoolean("checked", isChecked);
 editor.apply()
```

retrieving the data from sharedPreferences.
write the below code just below setContentView();

```
if(prefs.getBoolean("checked","")==true){
  checkBox.setChecked(true);
}
```